# Redirecting form jsf managed bean and showing js alert based on condition in managed bean

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, web-applications

Well, in my class Bean

```
package bean;

import entidade.Usuario;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author muky
 */

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BeanUsuario {

private Usuario usuario;

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

@PostConstruct
public void BeanUsuario() {
    if (usuario == null) {
        usuario = new Usuario();
    }
}

public void verificarUsuario(String login, String senha) {
    //UsuarioJpaController usuarioJPA = new UsuarioJpaController();        
    //usuarioJPA.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Usuario.findByLoginSenha").setParameter("login", login).setParameter("senha", senha).getResultList();

}
}
```

my XHTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form id="usuario" prependId="false">  

            <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5" style="">  

                <h:outputLabel for="login" value="Login:" style="font-weight:bold"/>           
                <p:inputText id="login" value="#{beanUsuario.usuario.login}" /> 

                <h:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha:" style="font-weight:bold"/>           
                <p:inputText id="senha" value="#{beanUsuario.usuario.senha}" />

                <p:commandButton value="Entrar" ajax="false" actionListener="#{beanUsuario.verificarUsuario(login, senha)}"/>  


            </h:panelGrid>  



        </h:form> 


    </h:body>
</html>
```

I need to check login and password (senha) if are correct, if yes, they are redirected to other page, else an alert box appears denying access! I'm startin' javaweb and not idea :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the values into your `beanUsuario.verificarUsuario` method (if you really want) like bellow:

```
#{beanUsuario.verificarUsuario(beanUsuario.usuario.login, beanUsuario.usuario.senha)}"
```

But I think you dont really need to pass arguments in `verificarUsuario` method, because you are binding the values of the input text to the managedBean property `usuario`. So you can simply write the method:

```
public void verificarUsuario() {
//UsuarioJpaController usuarioJPA = new UsuarioJpaController();
usuarioJPA.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Usuario.findByLoginSenha").setParameter("login", usuario.getLogin()).setParameter("senha", usuario.getSenha()).getResultList();

  if(canLogin){ //canLogin is the condition to check whether can login or not
      ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
      ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/home.xhtml");
  }
  else{
       showAlert = true;
  }
}
```

you get the values by only calling `usuario.getLogin()` and `usuario.getSenha()` in the method. You put `showAlert` variable in your managedBean and then in jsf page you can use the `<h:outputScript>` tag like this:

```
 <h:outputScript rendered="#{beanUsuario.showAlert}">
   alert("Invalid login");
</h:outputScript>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Yeah, this helped me a lot, but how i do for redirected to other page if login and senha are correct, else show alert box, how do i do it?

Comment: @user2051012 I have included the code to redirect by editing the answer!

Comment: great!! but and the alert box?

Comment: @user2051012, now I think it successfully adds alert box too!

Answer (score 1):

it will good if u have a dialog in xhtml page & if you want to show the Dialog just use.

RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.execute(“dialog.show()”);

& if u want to redirect then use Facescontext redirect("URL") method.

Hope it will help you.